# In React Native - is it possible to add a listener on an Animated Value received through props?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I have a `ScrollView` in my React Native app and I have several things that need to be done based on the current scroll position - some of them by the `ScrollView` itself and some affect animation in other Components.

Ideally I'd like to pass the `Animated.Value` of the scroll position to the other Components through their props and have them add a listener on the value and do their thing.  But as I understand the listener needs to be added in `componentWillMount`, where I don't yet have access to props.  So I'm forced to do all of the work of listening for the value in the top component that holds both the `ScrollView` and the other components that depend on it.

My **ideal code** would have been something like:

```
<MyTopComponent>
    <ScrollView onScroll={Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollPositionY}}}])}
    <OtherComponentA scrollPositionY={this.state.scrollPositionY} />
    <OtherComponentB />
</MyTopComponent>
```

And then inside `OtherComponentA`:

```
this.props.scrollPositionY.addListener(this._listener.bind(this));
```

But I can't do that in `OtherComponentA.componentWillMount` because the props aren't available yet.  So I have to do that in `MyTopComponent.componentWillMount`.

Am I missing something?
Is there another way to add a listener on an `Animated.Value` received through props?

Comment: Not sure that I fully understand the requirement but could you not pass a function reference (to the animated value) as the prop and just use the result of that function directly in the render of the target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the listener in `componentDidMount()` instead.

Comment: thanks!  that solved a really annoying design issue for me

Comment: No problem. Glad that I could help :)